# Revisions of a question still shows "closed" instead of "on hold"

Tags: bug, closed-questions, revisions-list, wording, on-hold

Let's start with an [example post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022574/how-to-create-a-delphi-application-with-multi-frames-history-of-navigation) which was placed on hold as off topic (I know recently "Closed" was changed to "On Hold" for the first 5 days). When viewing, it says "on hold"...
[image]

But, if you [view the edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18022574/revisions), it still shows the word "Closed".
[image]

Shouldn't this instance also be re-worded to "on hold" like elsewhere?

Comment: Okay, that example is no longer valid, will have to find another

Comment: http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1592/post-closed-activity-should-say-post-put-on-hold?noredirect=1#comment3850_1592 Still an issue, I just noted it on UX.SE.